# How do I revert Dist-upgrade on Ubuntu 20

Tags: upgrade, kali, katoolin

I ran a dist-upgrade on my Ubuntu 20 machine and ran into some error with the packages. I tried to `apt —-fix-broken` but I was still unable to get past the errors.  I decided to do a reboot and I now have Kali in my startup instead of Ubuntu. However while trying to boot Kali is stuck in `Failed to start mailman master queue`. I’ve done some research and believe this was caused by katoolin. I’ve had katoolin with only a few select tool on my pc for a long time and done several dist-upgrades and never run into this problem. Any ideas how I can reverse this process and boot back into my Ubuntu directly without a fresh install?

Comment: Yes, it definitely was caused by Katolin. The instructions explicitly say to remove the repos after installing the tools. And *I’ve had katoolin with only a few select tool on my pc for a long time and done several dist-upgrades and never run into this problem* is simply not true. Any update to the system with the Kali repos would turn it into Kali. Please reinstall.

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately it didn’t work for me . But I was able to remove katoolin in tty and recover  Ubuntu. The only problem is my desktop wouldn’t load. I’ve tried sudo apt-get install Ubuntu-desktop but I get an error of unmet dependencies. When I tried sudo aptitude  install Ubuntu-desktop I get held or brokers packages error.  I also noticed that when apt update also won’t fetch repositories even though I’m connect to my wifi.